# Linux command that returns current CPU usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu-usage

Is there a command or utility that can return the current CPU usage?

just like whats shown on `htop`.
[htop usage view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM2Ai.png)

so that:

```
command
```

Output:

```
70.0%
44.4%
```

Answer (score 1):

First, read [this](https://www.idnt.net/en-US/kb/941772).

Here is an excerpt from that link which has an important concept:

> The CPU usage can be measured over an interval of time only.

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325584/cpu-usage-in-top-batch-mode) has an example of using `top` in batch mode and `awk` to extract the CPU usage over a time from the output of `top`.

[There are other commands as well](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/check-cpu-usage-load-linux) that monitor CPU usage over an interval and report results via command line.